# Sum pairwise rows with R?

Tags: r, row, sum

My input is

```
 df1 <- data.frame(Row=c("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4", "row5"),
                   A=c(1,2,3,5.5,5), 
                   B=c(2,2,2,2,0.5),
                   C= c(1.5,0,0,2.1,3))
```

It look like this:

```
#  Row1 1   2   1.5
#  Row2 2   2   0
#  Row3 3   2   0
#  Row4 5.5 2   2.1
#  Row5 5   0.5 3
```

I want to get the sum of all these pairs of rows, with the following equation. Let's said for Row1 and Row2 pairs:  I want to multiply each column's entry and sum them into one final answer, for example-

- Row1-Row2 answer is `(1*2) + (2*2)+ (1.5 *0)` = `6`
- Row1-Row3 answer is `(1*3) + (2*2) + (1.5*0)` = `7`

I want to do all analysis for each pairs of row and get a result data frame like this:

```
row1    row2    6
row1    row3    7
row1    row4    12.65
row1    row5    10.5
row2    row3    10
row2    row4    15
row2    row5    11
row3    row4    20.5
row3    row5    16
row4    row5    34.8
```

How can I do this with R?  Thanks a lot for comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create all the combinations you need with `combn`. `t` is used to transpose the matrix as you expect it to be formatted.
2. Use `apply` to iterate over the indices created in step 1. Note that we use negative indexing so we don't try to sum the Row column.
3. Bind the two results together.

`

```
ind <- t(combn(nrow(df1),2))
out <- apply(ind, 1, function(x) sum(df1[x[1], -1] * df1[x[2], -1]))
cbind(ind, out)

           out
[1,] 1 2  6.00
[2,] 1 3  7.00
[3,] 1 4 12.65
 .....
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes! This is a matrix multiplication! :-))

First, just to prepare the matrix:

```
m = as.matrix(df1[,2:4])
row.names(m) = df1$Row
```

and this is the operation, how easy!

```
m %*% t(m)
```

That's it!

One tip - you could define the data.frame this way and it will save you the `row.names` command:

```
df1 <- data.frame(row.names=c("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4", "row5"),A=c(1,2,3,5.5,5), B=c(2,2,2,2,0.5), C= c(1.5,0,0,2.1,3))
```

Comment: add a not lower.tri selection and rearrange in there and you have something... he just wants combinations, not permutations.

Comment: thank's for the lower.tri tip, but I guess the rearrange step will be difficult - is there any elegant way?

Comment: @Tomas - I'll leave it to you to judge elegance, but `melt` from package reshape can be of use: `require(reshape); subset(melt(out2), as.numeric(X1) > as.numeric(X2))`. +1 for the matrix multiplication bit as well, I wasn't thinking that cleverly.