# How to create a matrix by sequential comparison of dataframe columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows (dput too long)

```
      $ OC_AH_026C.chr      : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ OC_AH_026C.leftPos  : num  240000 1080000 1200000 1320000 1440000 1800000 2400000 2520000 3120000 3360000 ...
 $ OC_AH_026C.Means    : num  78.1 81.8 156.5 26.8 18.5 ...
 $ OC_AH_026C.UL       : num  125 125 125 125 125 ...
 $ OC_AH_026C.LL       : num  1.95 1.95 1.95 1.95 1.95 ...
 $ OC_AH_026C.res      : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 ...
 $ OC_AH_026C.1.chr    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ OC_AH_026C.1.leftPos: num  240000 1080000 1200000 1320000 1440000 1800000 2400000 2520000 3120000 3360000 ...
 $ OC_AH_026C.1.Means  : num  97.3 88.9 50.1 33.3 44.2 ...
 $ OC_AH_026C.1.UL     : num  125 125 125 125 125 ...
 $ OC_AH_026C.1.LL     : num  2.45 2.45 2.45 2.45 2.45 ...
 $ OC_AH_026C.1.res    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ OC_AH_026T.chr      : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ OC_AH_026T.leftPos  : num  240000 1080000 1200000 1320000 1440000 1800000 2400000 2520000 3120000 3360000 ...
 $ OC_AH_026T.Means    : num  12.8 101.7 124 56.1 91.3 ...
 $ OC_AH_026T.UL       : num  126 126 126 126 126 ...
 $ OC_AH_026T.LL       : num  1.83 1.83 1.83 1.83 1.83 ...
 $ OC_AH_026T.res      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ OC_AH_058T.chr      : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ OC_AH_058T.leftPos  : num  240000 1080000 1200000 1320000 1440000 1800000 2400000 2520000 3120000 3360000 ...
 $ OC_AH_058T.Means    : num  103 119 201 118 96 ...
 $ OC_AH_058T.UL       : num  124 124 124 124 124 ...
 $ OC_AH_058T.LL       : num  0.684 0.684 0.684 0.684 0.684 ...
 $ OC_AH_058T.res      : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

When comparing two columns with res in the column name, I would like to get the number of rows where the res number is either both 1 or both -1 for the same row.

I would like to deposit this in a matrix so that I end up with something like

```
               OC_AH_026C.res   OC_AH_026C.1.res  OC_AH_026T.res   OC_AH_058T.res
OC_AH_026C.res
OC_AH_026C.1.res
OC_AH_026T.res
OC_AH_058T.res
```

I'm afraid I have only got as far as here but basically its all wrong

```
    df_list2res <- df_list2[,grep('*.res', names(df_list2))]

    Comparison<-lapply(df_list2res,function(df,col3){
  matches<-df_list2res[which(col3==col3),] #Should compare one column with all the other columns 
  nrow(subset(df_list2res,col != 0))
})
```

but the function to do the row by row comparison for each column and then dump in a matrix has defeated me.

**EDIT**

Using a limited dput

```
structure(list(OC_AH_026C.res = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_026C.1.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_026T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_058T.res = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_084T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_086T.res = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("OC_AH_026C.res", "OC_AH_026C.1.res", 
"OC_AH_026T.res", "OC_AH_058T.res", "OC_AH_084T.res", "OC_AH_086T.res"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The expected output would be (I think- done manually)

```
                   OC_AH_026C.res OC_AH_026C.1.res OC_AH_026T.res OC_AH_058T.res OC_AH_084T.res OC_AH_086T.res

OC_AH_026C.res         1            0                 0              1               0               1
OC_AH_026C.1.res       0            0                 0              0               0               0
OC_AH_026T.res         0            0                 0              0               0               0
OC_AH_058T.res         1            0                 0              1               0               1
OC_AH_084T.res         0            0                 0              0               0               0
OC_AH_086T.res         1            0                 0              1               0               1
```

Using a further dput output

```
    structure(list(OC_AH_026C.res = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), OC_AH_026C.1.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_026T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_058T.res = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0), OC_AH_084T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_086T.res = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0), OC_AH_088T.res = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0), OC_AH_096T.res = c(0, 
0, 0, -1, 0), OC_AH_100T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_127T.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_133T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ED_008T.res = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0), OC_ED_016T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ED_031T.res = c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 0), OC_ED_036T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_GS_001T.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), OC_QE_062T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_RS_010T.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), OC_RS_027C.res = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), OC_RS_027C.1.res = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0), OC_RS_027T.res = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), OC_SH_051T.res = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0), OC_ST_014T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_016T.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_020T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_024T.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_033T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_034C.res = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0), OC_ST_034C.1.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_036T.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_037T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_040T.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), OC_WG_001T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_WG_002T.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), OC_WG_005T.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_WG_009T.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), OC_WG_019T.res = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), Means.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), sd.res = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0)), .Names = c("OC_AH_026C.res", 
"OC_AH_026C.1.res", "OC_AH_026T.res", "OC_AH_058T.res", "OC_AH_084T.res", 
"OC_AH_086T.res", "OC_AH_088T.res", "OC_AH_096T.res", "OC_AH_100T.res", 
"OC_AH_127T.res", "OC_AH_133T.res", "OC_ED_008T.res", "OC_ED_016T.res", 
"OC_ED_031T.res", "OC_ED_036T.res", "OC_GS_001T.res", "OC_QE_062T.res", 
"OC_RS_010T.res", "OC_RS_027C.res", "OC_RS_027C.1.res", "OC_RS_027T.res", 
"OC_SH_051T.res", "OC_ST_014T.res", "OC_ST_016T.res", "OC_ST_020T.res", 
"OC_ST_024T.res", "OC_ST_033T.res", "OC_ST_034C.res", "OC_ST_034C.1.res", 
"OC_ST_036T.res", "OC_ST_037T.res", "OC_ST_040T.res", "OC_WG_001T.res", 
"OC_WG_002T.res", "OC_WG_005T.res", "OC_WG_009T.res", "OC_WG_019T.res", 
"Means.res", "sd.res"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you show the dput of a small dataset i.e. `dput(droplevels(df1[1:6, 1:6]))` and the expected output based on that.

Comment: I have edited the code with a reproducible example

Comment: Tried again although I dont think I can produce the desired output from this dput as Im doing it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an adaptation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933788/r-compare-all-the-columns-pairwise-in-matrix) answer to your particular question:

```
res <- apply(dat, 2, function(x) colSums(x == dat & abs(x) == 1))

> res
                 OC_AH_026C.res OC_AH_026C.1.res OC_AH_026T.res OC_AH_058T.res OC_AH_084T.res OC_AH_086T.res
OC_AH_026C.res                1                0              0              1              0              1
OC_AH_026C.1.res              0                0              0              0              0              0
OC_AH_026T.res                0                0              0              0              0              0
OC_AH_058T.res                1                0              0              1              0              1
OC_AH_084T.res                0                0              0              0              0              0
OC_AH_086T.res                1                0              0              1              0              1
```

Edit: same can be done using lapply:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(dat, function(x) colSums(x==dat & abs(x) == 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Which part of the code compares the same row for two columns. Is it x == dat?.

Comment: Yes, it does. The abs(x)-part checks if it's 1 or -1.

Comment: Also if I want to only count rows that both have -1 or both have 1 (rather than both have non-zero) is my edit of your code correct?

Comment: My code already did that. Your code from the edit tested if x was not 0. So, in my code it wouldn't count if x were 2, but in your code it would.

Comment: Oh. OK I'll change it back. Thanks